# What are the materials needed for boiling milk alarm sensor?

Tags: raspberry-pi, temperature, python

I have recently bought raspberry pi to start working on it. I have never ever used it before. I am thinking of doing very basic task of led bulb on/off for getting into it. I am curious on developing the system which senses for milk boiling so that I can develop a temperature alarm. It continuously measures the temperature of the milk and sounds an alarm when the milk is about to overflow from the stove.

What should I be equipped with to achieve the above project besides programming? Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: You need a temperature sensor. There are a lot of Raspi tutorials featuring an DS18B20. Look for it.

Comment: @Janka Maybe you should write an answer.

Comment: Just the temperature sensor would work? Do I need additional resource for just measuring the temperature of boiling milk instead of room temperature? Can you explain a bit, please?

Comment: You'll need a pressure sensor or altitude input, too.

Comment: It seems to me that when the temperature stops going up, the milk is about to boil over. Regardless of altitude, etc.

Comment: I foresee lots of interesting experiments (and big messes) in your household before this functions properly.  Do make sure to pick a temperature sensor intended for use in food, and make sure that no soldered connections can get in the milk.

Comment: @mkeith that assumes linear heating. Unfortunately, milk itself seems to have some interesting secondary boiling effects. Every time I boil milk, the milk boils, or more accurately, rapidly expands, on the outside before it boils in the middle. Average temperature may not be sufficient.

Comment: Or you could just buy a wooden spoon.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jd_y2d88SM